# Get mysql rows where date timestamp is 30 days or newer

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a bunch of mysql rows from the last 30 days using this sql:

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE date >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) ORDER BY `views` DESC
```

I am obviously doing something wrong as this returns rows from last year.

My date field in a gmt timestamp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your date field is not a `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP`, or `DATE` field type (as I think you're indicating with "in a GMT timestamp" - I suspect you're storing the integer itself), you're not going to be able to do comparison like that. You'd need to convert the 30 days ago date into a timestamp too.

```
WHERE date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY))
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
ORDER BY `views` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `articles` 
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
ORDER BY `views` DESC
```